# Getting the min and max value in JavaScript, but from a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this gets asked again and again but hear me out - this question is slightly different.

I can get a max or min from a 1D array like this:

```
var w_max = Math.max.apply(Math, myArray); 
var w_min = Math.min.apply(Math, myArray);
```

But my array is of the type:

```
[[[1, 112.0],[2,5.12],[3,113.1],[4,33.6],[5,85.9],[6,219.9]]]
//max = 219.9, min = 5.12
```

and I need to get min and max of the second value, with the first value being an index of sorts. I've tried

```
myArray[][], myArray[0][0], myArray[[1]]
```

and more. Console logging shows I'm getting NaN or -Infinity!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can map the array to the second values of the elements:

```
var arr = [[[1, 112.0],[2,5.12],[3,113.1],[4,33.6],[5,85.9],[6,219.9]]];
var values = arr[0].map(function(elt) { return elt[1]; });
var max = Math.max.apply(null, values);
var min = Math.min.apply(null, values);
```

Comment: @Aheinlein - Thanks. It's probably nowhere near as efficient as explicitly looping and testing (since it involves three iterations plus constructing a new array instead of a single iteration), but unless its a gigantic array and/or this is being done a huge number of times, the performance penalty will be negligible. There's a lot to be said for readability and maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ted Hopp. You've answered my question in the simplest way. Fwiw - my array will only ever have a maximum of 365 elements (and usually less) as the code only looks back one year.

Answer (score 12):

I really admired the sleek readability of @TedHopp 's solution -- so much so that I decided to adapt it into a function. The practicality of the function is still yet to be seen, but I liked the idea of being able to identify the `min` / `max` of a specified index within a 2D array.

```
function getMinMaxOf2DIndex (arr, idx) {
    return {
        min: Math.min.apply(null, arr.map(function (e) { return e[idx]})),
        max: Math.max.apply(null, arr.map(function (e) { return e[idx]}))
    }
}
```

**getMinMaxOf2DIndex()** takes two parameters, `arr` -- an array, and `idx` the index of the values to compare.

Usage Examples:

```
// using the OP's array as an example
var array = [[1, 112.0],[2,5.12],[3,113.1],[4,33.6],[5,85.9],[6,219.9]];

getMinMaxOf2DIndex(array, 0); // {min: 1, max: 6}
getMinMaxOf2DIndex(array, 1); // {min: 5.12, max: 219.9}

// and so on...
var array = [[1, 9, 6 , 3], [2, 4, 7, 2], [6, 5, 9, 4]];
getMinMaxOf2DIndex(array, 2); // {min: 1, max: 6}
getMinMaxOf2DIndex(array, 3); // {min: 6, max: 9}
```

Comment: I really admire your solution and if I could tick two answers I'd tick your too. But Ted came up with it first. I really like your adaptation of his solution.

Comment: I like this generalization as well. +1. However, I'd suggest using a local variable to store the result of `arr.map(...)`. There's no reason to do all the work twice of constructing an array of the values of interest.

Comment: it will cause range error :: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 7):

for big 2D arrays use this avoid function.prototype.apply as in above almost all answers i can see it. because it can handle only limited amount of array length .

```
function MaxMin2dray(arr, idx){
    var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
    var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
     arr.forEach(function(e) {
     if (max < e[idx]) {
      max = e[idx];
    }
    if (min > e[idx]) {
      min = e[idx];
    }
  });
  return {max: max, min: min};
}
```

Comment: This answer is the most efficient because it does not create additional arrays and performs only 1 iteration. Best solution here +1

Comment: Great! I see it doesn't work when the index passed is a date, which is what I'm after now.

Answer (score 5):

In `ES6` you can use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
var max = Math.max(...arrayOfValues);
```

Working example:

```js
var arr = [[[1, 112.0],[2,5.12],[3,113.1],[4,33.6],[5,85.9],[6,219.9]]];

var v = arr[0].map(e => e[1]);

var max = Math.max(...v);
var min = Math.min(...v);

console.log('max: ' + max);
console.log('min: ' + min);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying it is 2D array then it should have one less []

```
var myArray = [[1, 112.0],[2,5.12],[3,113.1],[4,33.6],[5,85.9],[6,219.9]];
var w_max=+Infinity;
var w_min=-Infinity;

for(var i=0;i< myArray.length;i++){
    elementArray = myArray[i];
    if(w_max < Math.max.apply(Math, elementArray)){
        w_max = Math.max.apply(Math, elementArray);
    } 
    if (w_min > Math.min.apply(Math, elementArray)){
        w_min = Math.min.apply(Math, elementArray);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That array you have in the post is interesting, but this works for it.

```
var array = [[[1, 112.0],[2,5.12],[3,113.1],[4,33.6],[5,85.9],[6,219.9]]];
function getMax(a){
    var max = a[0][0][1];
    for(var i = 0; i< a[0].length; i++){
        if(a[0][i][1] > max)
            max = a[0][i][1];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: If the array was supposed to be [[1, 112.0],[2,5.12],[3,113.1],[4,33.6],[5,85.9],[6,219.9]] (one less []) then you can use the same, but remove the [0]. it would be a[0][1] and a[i][1]

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = [
  [1, 112.0],
  [2, 5.12],
  [3, 113.1],
  [4, 33.6],
  [5, 85.9],
  [6, 219.9]
];

function getMinMax(list) {

  var min = +Infinity;
  var max = -Infinity;

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var touple = list[i];

    var val = touple[1];
    console.log(touple);
    console.log(val);

    min = Math.min(min, val);
    max = Math.max(max, val);
  }

  return {
    min: min,
    max: max
  };

}

console.log(getMinMax(list));
```

Comment: Just noticed that I `unnested` your inner array since it was actually an array of arrays of arrays -- a `3D` array, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the first array (the only one here) with a forEach:

```
var A= [
    [[1, 112.0], [2, 5.12], [3, 113.1], [4, 33.6], [5, 85.9], [6, 219.9]]
];
var mm= [Infinity, -Infinity];

A[0].forEach(function(itm){
    var n= itm[1];
    if(n<mm[0]) mm[0]= n;
    if(n>mm[1]) mm[1]= n;   
});
```

mm

/*  returned value: (Array) [5.12, 219.9]
*/

Answer (score -1):

The first answer is not correct!!!

```
let arr = [[1, 112.0],[2,5.12],[3,113.1],[4,33.6],[5,85.9],[6,219.9]];
let values = Array.concat.apply([],arr);
let max = Math.max(...values);
let min = Math.min(...values);
console.log(arr)
console.log(min)//1
console.log(max)//219.9
console.log(values)//[ 1, 112, 2, 5.12, 3, 113.1, 4, 33.6, 5, 85.9, 6, 219.9 ]
```

Comment: That's AMAZING!!!!.  But, much better than a bold declaration, and a code dump, would be some explanation about why your answer is the ONE.