# Getting the max value from an array within an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just starting to learn Javascript and Angular.
I have an array within an array.

This is my array structure:

[[object1, object2],[object3, object 4]];

I want to get the highest value from object2 and object 4.

When i only had one array i used

```
Math.max.apply(Math, array.map(function(o){return o.collectionID;}));
```

Is it possible and how can i retrieve the highest value from an array within an array?

Comment: apply it to `parentArray[n]`?

Comment: Can you post your array structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could collect all `id` with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for any depth arrays.

Then take only `collectionID` where it is set.

```js
var array = [[{}, { collectionID: 1 }], [{}, { collectionID: 2 }], [{}, { collectionID: 3 }], [{ collectionID: 42 }, { collectionID: 4 }]],
    max = Math.max.apply(Math, array.reduce(function iter(r, a) {
        return r.concat(Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce(iter, []) : 'collectionID' in a ? a.collectionID : []);
    }, []));
    
console.log(max);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! My array format is 
[[{object},{collectionID: 1}],[{object},{collectionID: 2}]] How could i choose the second object in the array?

Comment: I mean the collectionID object isn't always the second of the array.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the very simple and powerful answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/23397247/3455035]